# Replace push in array works but splice never called

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, splice

Having a Array like this:

```
var k =[1,2];
k.push(3);
```

redefine push like this:

```
function kPush(e){
  this[this.length] = e * 2;
}
Object.defineProperty(k, 'push', {
  get: function(){return kPush;}
});
```

And calling using

```
k.push(4);
document.write(k);
```

Gives:

```js
var k =[1,2];
k.push(3);
function kPush(e){
  this[this.length] = e * 2;
}
Object.defineProperty(k, 'push', {
  get: function(){return kPush;}
});
k.push(4);
document.write(k);
```

Gives:

```
1,2,3,8
```

Everythings fine. Now I need to overwride `splice` but its never called.

```
Object.defineProperty(k, 'splice', {
  get: function(){return kSplice;}
});
```

But

```
console.debug(k.splice);
```

gives me `function splice() { [native code] }`. <-- its native? But i have overwritten the property!

How to overwrite `splice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var k =[1,2];
k.push(3);
function kPush(e){
  this[this.length] = e;
}
Object.defineProperty(k, 'push', {
  get: function(){return kPush;}
});
Object.defineProperty(k, 'splice', {
  get: function(){return function(){
    console.log("Splice");
   Array.prototype.splice.apply(this,arguments);
    }}
});
k.push(4);
k.splice(1,1);
document.write(k);
```

Comment: i think your kSplice function is reference to the native function